# Asking for an example of stiff ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am currently studying on the numerical solutions of ODEs and I'm trying to calculate the difference of the exact solution to numerically evaluated solution and then just plot the absolute difference. I'm doing this so I can eventually see how good these numerical methods can actually calculate the error. For example, here is an example from numerical recipes:

$$u' = 998u + 1998v$$
$$v' = -999u - 1999v$$

with boundary conditions

$$u(0) = 1 $$
$$v(0) = 0$$
With the exact (analytical) solution of
$$u = 2e^{-x} − e^{-1000x} $$
$$v = -e^{-x} + e^{-1000x} $$
Now when I use the BDF method with rtol=1e-12,atol=1e-30 and plot the differences, I get:

[image]
[image]

Now the thing is, I think these equations aren't just stiff enough to really challenge the solver, and I'm looking for a multi-scale ODE with difference of at least $10^{10}$ which has an exact solution. Can anyone suggest such an ODE?

Comment: BDF is supposed to be good at stiff equations, right? So at least it makes sense that BDF is doing well on that example. Maybe a method like RK4 would struggle more.

Comment: Have you tried adding more "$9$"s to your example?  (I.e., $998 \mapsto 10^{10} - 2$, $999 \mapsto 10^{10} - 1$, $1998 \mapsto 2 \times 10^{10} - 2$, and $1999 \mapsto 2 \times 10^{10} - 1$)

Comment: I don't think just changing both scales equally would actually make the equations "multi-scale", or would it?

Comment: @EricTowers To be more precise, I want an ODE which one of its variables solution is in the order of 5 and the other one in the order of -5 (10^5 , 10^-5)

Comment: What do you mean with "challange the solver", what do you expect to see? Perhaps something similar as you get when changing `method="BDF"` to `method="Radau"` or `"DOP853"`? Are you using `solve_ivp`, and what version of `scipy` (here 1.7.1)? In my reproduction of this experiment the tails of the error curve are less oscillating, the defect around $t=60$ does not happen in my graph. /// It is instructive to see the step size in a log-log graph, `x = res.t; h = x[1:]-x[:-1]; plt.loglog(x[:-1],h, "-s",ms=2, lw=0.5)`, as one can see 3 or 4 mode switches in the step size evolution.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I'm just trying to see up to what significant digit it can evaluate the ODE. In other words, for example, if our system of equations has two variables which one of them has a solution in the order of $10^{8}$ and the other one in the order of $10^{-8}$, can it actually meet its (relative) tolerance of  1e-12 and calculate each solution up to 12 significant digits? This is my question.

Comment: No, that usually does not happen, the solvers usually do not detect the component scales automatically. The newer solvers, and also the solvers in Matlab, support arrays for the tolerances, so that one can set them according to the scale of the components. Without that the step size requirements for very small components get shadowed by the absolute tolerance if it is oriented on the large components, so that the small component accumulate large relative errors.

Comment: I've seen this in circuit simulation and celestial simulation if using the km-sec unit system. The latter is reduces if using the AU-day unit system. But this is not really about stiffness.

Comment: But the only post I found discussing approximately this topic, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65667469/validation-of-tolerance-in-runge-kutta-fehlberg, has no easily discernible category.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Yes, that post was also me. Now I'm just looking for a system of ODE that has an exact solution to test all the things we discussed. Do you have any thoughts on this?

Comment: You have a system of linear ODEs with constant coefficients. You are free to choose the eigenvalues of the matrix, right? Will the case of $\lambda_1=-1$ and $\lambda_2=-10^{12}$ satisfy your needs?

Comment: @CarlChristian I think yes.

Comment: If it works, then do not hesitate to write it up as a detailed answer.